# Gmail displays contacts as "[Contact Name] personal"

Tags: gmail, google-contacts

I've noticed that recently (starting a few months ago) some of my contacts started being displayed as "Jane personal" instead of her actual name like "Jane Doe" in emails.

I find this format strange, but I can't figure out any way to get it to return to the old way. In addition this appears to only have happened to one of my contacts, but her name appears correctly in Google contacts.

Other people who she emails has mentioned seeing the same behavior--so it could be related to her Gmail account in some way.

Another interesting tidbit that I just noticed is that this doesn't occur 100% of the time. Some emails still have the name displayed in the "Jane Doe" format.

Comment: I'll look into it. UPDATE: I don't think it has anything to do with Categories, as I've never used that feature either.

Comment: Ok I found the source but not how to fix it (yet). When she sends emails from her browser, the name is displayed as "Jane Doe." When sent from her iPhone it is in the format "Jane personal." I'm not sure why this is, but I know the phone is causing it in some way.

Comment: Pretty much! If I don't find more info on this soon, I'll write up an answer. (I can't do one yet, due to new-user restrictions on this SO site.)

Comment: It was a setting on the phone!--so not directly related to a Web Application (oops!). I've asked her to write up an answer of how she fixed it in case others have the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only fix this by having the sender change the settings on their iPhone.

Using the steps below they can modify the name that is displayed to others:

Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars

Then select the account you would like to change. (Gmail, iMail, etc.)

On the next screen, click the email address associated with that account.

The new screen has an option to change the account "Name" to your choosing. It can be anything you like whether that be "Jane," "Jane Doe," or "Awesome Girl"--it is up to you.